# Different CSS class by category

Tags: categories, customization, css

UPDATE: I think this already may be in place, as i am able to assign icons to individual categories?

[image]

I am trying to customize a WP theme and I need different categories to be different CSS classes.

Example:

WP Category: Articles       > class="cat-1" 

WP Category: Blogs          > class="cat-2" 

WP Category: Press Releases > class="cat-3" 

WP Category: News           > class="cat-4"

I need to be able to style these differently. I am familiar with HTML/CSS but unfortunately I don't know much about PHP.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: depending on your theme, your site might already have category specific CSS classes via the `body_class()` or  `post_class()` functions https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/

Answer (score 1):

If your template uses the function `post_class()` in it then your posts already have category-based classes applied to them in the HTML. In PHP, it often will look like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

For example, say you have a category of `news`, then posts that are in it will have a class of `category-news` among others. It also will have classes for tags as well like `tag-{slug}` as well.

So in your CSS you can simply use `.category-news` or whatever the slug of your category is.

```
.category-news {
   background-color: #123;
}
```

And so forth.